# Remove nodes with neo4j.rb

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use jruby neo4j.rb is to delete all nodes from Neo4j database:

Neo4j._query ("START n = node (*) DELETE n")

The query runs fine but the nodes still Appear in Neo4j web admin.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has your transaction been committed?

Comment: How can I force the commit operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if your nodes have no relationships. Otherwise, you need to delete those also. You can use the Cypher query Michael gives in his answer: [Why does the cleandb extension refuse to delete my neo4j graph database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862852/why-does-the-cleandb-extension-refuse-to-delete-my-neo4j-graph-database)

If you don't have any relationships, perhaps is the webadmin that doesn't report correctly what it is in your DB. Have you tried counting the nodes with a Cypher query ?

start n=node(*) return count(n);

Comment: Yes, my nodes have relationships. I will test your suggestion and give you feedback later about that.

Comment: a clean-all would be `start n = node(*) match n-[r?]->() delete n, r`