# Why does the cleandb extension refuse to delete my neo4j graph database?

Tags: neo4j, neo4django

When trying to purge [*neo4j*](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j) (1.8.2) with the [*cleandb*](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-clean-remote-db-addon) extension (for neo4j 1.8), it fails:

```
[path] ? curl -v -X DELETE 'http://localhost:7475/db/cleandb/12sE$lkj3%'
* About to connect() to localhost port 7475 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7475 (#0)
> DELETE /db/cleandb/12sE$lkj3% HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:7475
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(6.1.25)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Obviously, I do not only get a 500 error code, also the db is not purged.
Of course, access URL and "secret-key" of the plugin are set up as used in the `curl` request:

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.server.extension.test.delete=/db/cleandb
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty.delete.key=12sE$lkj3%
```

I would conveniently add the *cleandb* tag, but I lack the 1500 reputation.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
(The reason I use cleandb is to set up unittests in neo4django).
**/EDIT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I have the cleandb extension working locally against 1.8.2 and 1.9. For example, you can run

```
from neo4django.db import connection
from pdb import set_trace; set_trace()
connection.cleandb()
```

and trace the `cleandb` Python call, and it gets a 200 and accompanying response body,

```
{\n  "node-indexes" : [ ],\n  "nodes" : 4,\n  "relationship-indexes" : [ ],\n  "relationships" : 0,\n  "maxNodesToDelete" : 1000\n}
```

I'm not sure what the difference between curl and the Python call might be- any chance you could try the above in a module, run it, and see what happens?

EDIT:

The cleandb extension is unmanaged, so you can't (IIRC?) set the URL to '/db/cleandb', it needs to be on its own root- I use '/cleandb'. LMK if that helps!

EDIT:

Aw, disregard that, '/db/' urls seem to work fine. Maybe you could use the 'install_local_neo4j.bash' script (https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/blob/master/install_local_neo4j.bash) to install a copy of Neo4j and set it up the same way, if that works for you? And if so, maybe we can see how the setups differ...

Comment: Ha! That's stupid! I removed the `$` and `%` sign from the secret key and now it **works**. _Either_ cleandb does not support special chars in the secret key, _or_ something went wrong with the URL encoding – maybe `curl` does not do that by itself, unlike browsers, and I should have provided the URL-encoded URL already. Actually, now I suspect the `$` to be the culprit (though both have special meaning in URLs). Well, I guess I wanted to follow good password guidelines to well having special chars as well, and not only alphanumerics... :-)

Comment: @Michael Hunger: can you confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

It only works with Neo4j versions up to 1.7 I think.

Didn't update it anymore b/c you can do that cleanup with cypher now, see: http://neo4j.org/resources/cypher

```
start n=node(*)
match n-[r?]->()
where id(n) <> 0
delete n,r
```

Comment: Actually, there is a specific version for 1.8 [here](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-clean-remote-db-addon/downloads), (and I use this version matching my neo4j 1.8.2 (which I use because that's what neo4django is tested against).

Comment: In fact, I stumbled across cleandb because it's the suggested way of doing unittests in neo4django

Comment: @ASz neo4django master is also tested against 1.9RC1. I've been meaning to update the Travis CI build from 1.9RC1 to 1.9, but I'm pretty certain everything still works, since I test against 1.9 as I develop. I'll switch it right away and update the docs.

Comment: @Matt, I know `cleandb`is not your project, but do you have any ideas why my cleandb setup does not work? Did I miss something? (Especially as I'm using 1.8.2 to be on the safe side with neo4django).

Comment: @MichaelHunger: if I enter this cypher query into the console on `1.9`, I get an error message that the nodes cannot be deleted because there are still relationships connected to them. Could you update the query to work?